# How To Create Reset Password Using NextAuth, with credential provider

Tags: authentication, next.js, passwords, next-auth, forgot-password

How can i create a simple reset password using next auth Credential provider with mongo db
i have user schema like this

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema<UserSchemaType>(
    {
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
        password: { type: String, required: true },
        img: { type: String, required: true },
        isAdmin: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: false },
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
);
```

my next auth look like this

```
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            async authorize(credentials) {
                await db.connect();
                const user = await User.findOne({
                    email: credentials.email,
                });

                if (user && bcryptjs.compareSync(credentials.password, user.password)) {
                    return {
                        _id: user._id,
                        name: user.name,
                        email: user.email,
                        image: user.img,
                        isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
                    };
                }
                throw new Error('Invalid email or password');
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```

is there a simple example for implementing reset password with the next auth

Answer (score 4):

I do not think that `next-auth` provides any special functionality for this. You have to implement a general flow. User should have `Forgot Password` button and you send the request to next.js api backend. "pages/api/forgot.js"

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

handler.post(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await db.connectDb();
    const { email } = req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Email does not exist." });
    }
   // create token with jwt 
    const user_token =jwt.sign(user._id, process.env.RESET_TOKEN_SECRET, {
expiresIn: "1h",
});
    // you should create "pages/reset/[token].js" dynamic page
    const url = `${process.env.BASE_URL}/reset/${user_id}`;
    // you need to implement sedning email maybe using `nodemailer`
    // create this function for your case
    sendEmail(email, url, "Reset your password.");
    // you should disconnect the db here
    res.json({
      message: "An email has been sent to you to reset your password.",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});
```

"pages/reset/[token].js" page you will have a form that has 2 inputs. "password" and "confirm Password". Once user clicks on reset button, you sent the password and decrypted token (we created the token with user_id) to another backend api: "pages/api/reset.js". this backend will take `user_id` and password, query the db and change the password

```
handler.put(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await db.connectDb();
    const { user_id, password } = req.body;
    const user = await User.findById(user_id);
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Account does not exist." });
    }
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);
    await user.updateOne({
      password: hashedPassword,
    });
    res.status(200).json({ email: user.email });
    // you should disconnect the db 
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs - https://next-auth.js.org/providers/credentials

> The functionality provided for credentials based authentication is
> intentionally limited to discourage use of passwords due to the
> inherent security risks associated with them and the additional
> complexity associated with supporting usernames and passwords.

Probably you can use the Email Provider and customise if you really want this feature.

https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/email

Comment: I want to live my life dangerously with credentials. 